# The Content-Security-Policy directive 'frame-ancestors' does not support the source expression ''unsafe-inline'' for allowed site

Tags: magento2, content-security-policy

I am working on a Magento 2 site with a custom extension to add a whitelist to Magento's CSP. I am running into an issue with the following error: "The Content-Security-Policy directive 'frame-ancestors' does not support the source expression ''unsafe-inline''"

The source of this issue is the following file: https://translate.googleapis.com/element/TE_20210503_00/e/js/element/element_main.js

The problem is, I have this site whitelisted under frame-ancestors, yet it's still being blocked. Here is the policy I have so far:

```
<policy id="frame-ancestors">
    <values>
        <value id="google-apis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
    </values>
</policy>
```

This is the same format I have for all other policies and all those policies have been whitelisted correctly. This is the only one that isn't being affected.

I have followed this tutorial for making my CSP extension, for reference: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/312350/73083

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, this is the last issue I need to fix before adding CSP to the site.

Comment: Eric, how did you fix this? Could you please share the solution as I've the exact issue?

Answer (score 4):

It has mentioned in 2.4.3 release Magento doc., this is still a known issue with Magento: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/open-source-2-4-3.html#known-issues. So, we can do is a temporary fix for being time.

The solution is to creating own custom module to extending the Magento_Csp module. In the etc/config.xml file we want to modify the frame-ancestor policy and set it to 0.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
<default>
    <csp>
        <policies>
            <storefront>
                <frame-ancestors>
                    <inline>0</inline>
                </frame-ancestors>
            </storefront>
            <admin>
                <frame-ancestors>
                    <inline>0</inline>
                </frame-ancestors>
            </admin>
        </policies>
    </csp>
</default>
```

Then run:

```
bin/magento s:up
bin/magento s:s:d -f
bin/magento c:f
```

This will help it's a working solution.

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 1):

1. `frame-ancestors` directive, indeed, does not support an `'unsafe-inline'` token. This token is supported by `script-src`, `style-src` and `default-src` directives only.

If you have got error: "The Content-Security-Policy directive 'frame-ancestors' does not support the source expression ''unsafe-inline''" this means you have a rule: `frame-ancestors ... 'unsafe-inline' ...;` in the CSP.
Possible you mistakenly publishes somewhere a *second CSP* with this rule. Or this error occurs in the *third-party iframe*, but not in your web app.

2. You have to use not `frame-ancestors` but `frame-src` directive if you wish to allow something like `<frame src='https://accounts.googleapis.com/auth/...'`. Because `frame-ancestors *.googleapis.com` controls an embedding your web site into `*.googleapis.com` web page. Whereas `frame-src` controls which sites are allowed to be embeded on your page.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an alternate way to do this based on Rohit's answer, instead of creating a module to override the config, it can be added to the database:

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
VALUES
('default', 0, 'csp/policies/admin/frame-ancestors/inline', '0'),
('default', 0, 'csp/policies/storefront/frame-ancestors/inline', '0');
```